# Making a Bitmap Clickable with a Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, clickable

Hopefully this is the last step in completing my app. I need to make a bitmap within a canvas clickable that will either call a new activity that will play a video (mp4) or within the current activity play the video.

The class that displays the canvas and bitmaps is a class I use over and over to display a full image of a thumbnail. The image id is passed through an Intent. Here is the code for the full image activity (I'm very much a noob and pieced my code together one step at a time using this site and others so I apologize if it's not clean):

```
public class full_image extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new BitmapView(this));
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.bground);
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations(0);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,                           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

class BitmapView extends View {
    public BitmapView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int imgid = getIntent().getIntExtra("Full",0);
        Bitmap fullimage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imgid);
        Bitmap playButton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bt_play); //Added for Video
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int fpWidth = fullimage.getWidth();
        int fpHeight = fullimage.getHeight();
        int playWidth = playButton.getWidth(); 
        int playHeight = playButton.getHeight(); 
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        int leftPoint = screenWidth/2 - fpWidth/2;
        int topPoint = screenHeight/2 - fpHeight/2;
        int leftPlayPoint = screenWidth/2 - playWidth/2; 
        int topPlayPoint = screenHeight/2 - playHeight/2; 
        canvas.drawBitmap(fullimage,leftPoint,topPoint,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(playButton,leftPlayPoint,topPlayPoint,null); 

    }
}  
}
```

If possible, I would like just the playButton to house the onClickListener but if it's easier, I'm Ok with making the whole canvas clickable (if that's even possible).

I read on another question where there was a suggestion to use TouchEvent. I tried going that route but could not get it to work. Is this the right path and I just need to play around with it more to get it to work?

Thanks, J

Additional Stuff:

here's a snippet of code I found in another question. Where would I put this code into the code provided above.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
int action = event.getAction();
int x = event.getX()  // or getRawX();
int y = event.getY();

switch(action){
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
            && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
        //tada, if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
    }
    break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we can't setOnClick on bitmap in canvas.
But we can use onTouch method for it. and check touch on bitmap or not using x-y position of touch.

try this code in onTouch method for get touch on bitmap...

```
if (x >= xOfYourBitmap && x < (xOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getWidth())
                && y >= yOfYourBitmap && y < (yOfYourBitmap + yourBitmap.getHeight())) {
            //tada, if this is true, you've started your click inside your bitmap
        }
```

Comment: Where would I put the onTouch method? I tried putting it outside the OnDraw area but then I can't reference my bitmap. When I tried putting it in the OnDraw area, I got errors. See my original question above. i added some additional code at the bottom. Any suggestions on where I add this code? Thanks

Comment: put it outside of OnDraw and inside of BitmapView(your class) and create local variable for bitmap...

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am right now. Worked on the first try. thanks so much for your help.